# choose between 2 possible number for elements of array to get the sum 's'

Tags: algorithm

I have some algorithmic problem, I have three array X, Y, and A size n, I have the values in X and Y but A is empty and I want to fill that so A[i] is either X[i] or Y[i], and I want to see if the sum of elements in A  can be some value S or not, if yes, how ??

I think this problem can be solved by dynamic programming, but I don't know how

also, I don't want some algorithm with time complexity more than O(n * n * log(n))

Comment: Is there any bounds on the numbers in X and Y?

Answer (score 0):

You can not solve this problem because at first 
`C = [min(x[0], y[0]), min(x[1], y[1]), min(x[2], y[2]),...]` 
after that you have `B = [abs(x[0] - y[0]), abs(x[1], y[1]), abs(x[2], y[2]), ...]` 
and you should have `T = (s - (SUM(C)))` 
and choose sum number from B equal to T and you cant solve it :|